# Como considerar um EditText vazio como "0"

Tags: java, android, edittext

Estou desenvolvendo um App de Android que faça calculo de matrizes 3x3
então eu tenho 18 `EditText`, porém se eu quiser multiplicar uma matriz 2x3, 2x2, 1x2, etc. eu teria que preencher os campos do tamanho da matriz e deixar os outros campos com o 0 e isso não iria mudar o resultado.

Eu fiz uma condição para ele avisar caso o campo esteja vazio porém o melhor seria ele considerar o campo vazio como "0" sem precisar que o usuário preencha todos os campos

Answer (score 3):

Isso pode ser facilmente conseguido se declarar o seu *EditText* com o seu valor por defeito igual a zero e indicar que ele só pode receber valores numéricos:

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edittext"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="0" 
   android:inputType="number"/>
```

O atributo [android:text="0"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:text) atribui o valor zero como valor por defeito.
O atributo [android:inputType="number"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) faz com que apenas valores inteiros seja aceites pelo *EditText*

Comment: Obgd, mas se o usario apagar o "0" o app vai crashar 
eu preciso que o app considere o campo vazio como o numero "0"

Comment: Quando isso acontecer o correcto, tal como você diz que já está fazendo, é avisar o usuário,

Comment: Note que agora já não obriga o usuário a preencher todos os campos, o zero vai aparecer por defeito.

Comment: Eu fiz oque  vc disse em todos os campos. E criei uma if que caso tenho algum campo vazio ele mostre um aviso ao invés de calcular, então ele não crasha, foi uma boa solução temporária, mas  se alguém tiver uma dica de como calcular o campo nulo como 0 eu fico muito grato

Answer (score 1):

Para obter o valor de seus `EditText` utilize esta função passando o mesmo como parâmetro

```
private int getValorEdit(EditText edit){

    int ret = 0;

    if (! edit.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        ret = Integer.valueOf(edit.getText().toString());
    }   
    return ret;

}
```

Espere ajuda-lo.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, porém ele continua nulo ao invés de mandar o numero "0"

Answer (score 1):

Nenhuma das correções acima funcionou pra mim.
Apenas esta:

```
if(txtEdit.getText().toString().equals("")){
  num = 0;
} else {
  num = parseInt(txtEdit.getText().toString());
}
```