# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, android-intent

O app não funciona ao fazer o deploy. Ele "crasha" direto.
Segue o codigo e o erro:
**ActMain.java**

```
package desenvmoveluss.com.br.trabalho01;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;

public class ActMain extends AppCompatActivity {
//implements View.OnClickListener
    private EditText edtA;
    private EditText edtB;
    private EditText edtC;
    private Button btnOK;
    public String resultado;

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

        a=0;
        b=0;
        c=0;

        edtA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtA);
        edtB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtB);
        edtC = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtC);
        btnOK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

        a = Integer.parseInt(edtA.getText().toString());
        b = Integer.parseInt(edtB.getText().toString());
        c = Integer.parseInt(edtC.getText().toString());


        if ((a < b + c) || (b < a + c) || (c < a+b)){

            //triangulo
            if((a==b) && (a==c) && (c==b)){
                resultado = "Triangulo Equilatero";

            }
            if((a==b) || (a==c) || (c==b)){
                resultado = "Triangulo Isosceles";
            }
            else{
                resultado = "Triangulo Escaleno";
            }
        }
        else{
            resultado = "Não é um triangulo";

        }


    }

    public void OnClick(View v){
        Intent it = new Intent(this, ActSegundaTela.class);
        it.putExtra("RESULTADO", resultado.toString());
        startActivity(it);

    }
}
```

**ActSegundaTela.java**

```
package desenvmoveluss.com.br.trabalho01;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

public class ActSegundaTela extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtResultado;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_segunda_tela);

        txtResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String resultado = intent.getExtras().getString("RESULTADO");
       //        String valor = bundle.getString("RESULTADO");

        txtResultado.setText(resultado);

    }
}
```

**Erro**

```
09-23 18:05:57.920 8864-8864/desenvmoveluss.com.br.trabalho01 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: desenvmoveluss.com.br.trabalho01, PID: 8864
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{desenvmoveluss.com.br.trabalho01/desenvmoveluss.com.br.trabalho01.ActMain}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at desenvmoveluss.com.br.trabalho01.ActMain.onCreate(ActMain.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Answer (score 3):

Você está a converter uma string vazia(`""`) em um inteiro.

```
a = Integer.parseInt(edtA.getText().toString());
```

Isso acontece porque ainda nada foi introduzido no *EditText*.

Sugiro que faça o seguinte:

Mova o código que faz o calculo para um novo método:

```
private String calcular(){

    int a = Integer.parseInt(edtA.getText().toString());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(edtB.getText().toString());
    int c = Integer.parseInt(edtC.getText().toString());


    if ((a < b + c) || (b < a + c) || (c < a+b)){

        //triangulo
        if((a==b) && (a==c) && (c==b)){
            resultado = "Triangulo Equilatero";

        }
        if((a==b) || (a==c) || (c==b)){
            resultado = "Triangulo Isosceles";
        }
        else{
            resultado = "Triangulo Escaleno";
        }
    }
    else{
        resultado = "Não é um triangulo";

    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Chame-o no método `OnClick()`:

```
public void OnClick(View v){
    String resultado = calcular();
    Intent it = new Intent(this, ActSegundaTela.class);
    it.putExtra("RESULTADO", resultado);
    startActivity(it);

}
```

Tenha atenção que o método `calcular()` não verifica se os valores introduzidos nos *EditText* são válidos, deve por isso clicar no botão apenas depois de introduzir neles valores inteiros.
Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89371/2541) para uma possível solução.

Comment: Esta é apenas uma sugestão de contorno do problema, que ainda continua presente caso o utilizador não preencha as caixas de texto e clique no botão

Comment: @MarceloUchimura A resposta faz referência a isso mesmo, porque a pergunta não é sobre isso. No entanto, vou editá-la, adicionado um link para uma resposta que resolve isso.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque valores padrão nas `EditText`s. `0` é um bom valor.

No momento em que for *parsear* os inteiros, faça:

```
    a = Integer.parseInt("0" + edtA.getText().toString());
    b = Integer.parseInt("0" + edtB.getText().toString());
    c = Integer.parseInt("0" + edtC.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Algun inteiro seu, esta com problema.

Inicia eles neste trecho:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
```

Use Log.d para verificar também.